# Finding the area of a polar region

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find the area inside the curve $$ r = 2 + \sin2\Theta + \cos3\Theta .$$ It's a very weird looking function after graphing, and I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to proceed. There's not an example like it in my textbook, which dealt mostly with symmetric functions, so I'm really confused. Any help is appreciated.

ADD: Okay, I see the formula, but I'm confused by how to set up the integral. The limits aren't entirely clear. Any advice?

Comment: There is the formula $S = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}r^2(\theta)\,d\theta.$

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see the formula, but I'm confused by how to set up the integral. The limits aren't entirely clear. Any advice?

Comment: There's the lower bound and the upper bound to find for $\theta$. You need to decide at which $\theta$ the curve starts and ends.

Comment: Looks like 2Pi and 0 on my end. Thanks!